# Gazebo real and simulation time

Tags: ros, gazebo, real-time, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

As running gazebo, I noticed the lower toolbar with RMS Error, xReal Time, Real time, etc. I'm wondering how exactly are computed all this times and why, when I'm roslaunching lots of nodes, xReal Time is decreasing (as the simulator is slower and the computer also) ?

If I missed some doc about that, please link.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35699/gazebo-real-and-simulation-time/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your `.world` file, you can specify the desired update rate for Gazebo using the `<updateRate>` tag.

```
<physics:ode>
   ...
   <stepTime>STEP_TIME</stepTime>
   <updateRate>UPDATE_RATE</updateRate>
   ...
</physics:ode>
```

The value of `<updateRate>` has three configurations:

1. UPDATE_RATE < 0: Gazebo will attempt to run the simulation in real time
2. UPDATE_RATE = 0: Gazebo will attempt to run the simulation as fast as possible
3. UPDATE_RATE > 0: This number will represent the desired physics update frequency. In this case, Gazebo will run STEP_TIME*UPDATE_RATE times reality.

If Gazebo is not able to update at your desired rate, it will update as fast as it can. It's based on the system's computing power, so more nodes = less CPU time for Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-06-05**:
Thanks for answering. Is there a default value if the tag isn't defined (if real time is 1.0, I think the default value is negative) ?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-06-05**:
I don't know what the default value is. Gazebo always runs at sub-real-time for me (about 0.75 real-time).

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-06-05**:
Okey, I'm gonna experience some values to check that. Thanks for help ! :)

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-06-25**:
Has this been tested to work in Fuerte? I am setting the parameter as you suggest but with no luck (the simulation in my case is running too fast, I would like real time)

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-06-25**:
This is for the Electric version of Gazebo. Fuerte migrated to Gazebo 1.0. I don't know how to do this in that version